# Custom method spring mongo repository gives no data back

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I've recently been playing with query creation from method name. I have this interface that extends MongoRepository:

```
public interface CompanyRepository extends MongoRepository<Company, String> {
    //this works.
    Company findByEmployeename(String name);
    //this doesn't
    List<Company> findByEmployeename(List<String> name);
}
```

I was hoping I could get back list of companies from a list of employees, but when I call the method I get back a empty list. I don't want to use `findByEmployeename(String name)` in a loop or some sort. Is this possible with a custom repository method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Just append `In` to `List<Company> findByEmployeenameIn(List<String> name);`, which translates to `$in` operator in Mongo query. You should just read up on https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.

If you wanna see the the corresponding query created by your method in the console logs. In your properties/yml file, add `logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG`